# find the encoded value of a categorical data via OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

so,
I have a dataset with one column with data of colors like below:

```
data = np.array([[1,'red', 14], [4,'blue',54], [2,'green', 241], [7,'blue',25]])
```

now I use ColumnTransform from sklearn.compose as follow:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([('cat',OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
transformed_data = ct.fit_transform(data)
```

new I have transformed_data as follow:

```
array([['0.0', '0.0', '1.0', '1', '14'],
       ['1.0', '0.0', '0.0', '4', '54'],
       ['0.0', '1.0', '0.0', '2', '241'],
       ['1.0', '0.0', '0.0', '7', '25']], dtype='<U32')
```

From this output we can infer taht the encoded value for 'red' color was [0 0 1].

now let's say I have a variable = 'blue' and I want to find based on the transformation that I have  made with the above data, what would be the encoded value via OneHotEncoder for this variable.

in other word is there a function or something in sklearn to give as its input this variable and
the function gives me back the encoded value. in this case the funciton gives me the value [1 0 0].

I am using python3 with sklearn.
Thanks.

I have tried following code.
ct.transform([['red'])
but there is the error saying X  has 1 features, but the ColumnTransformer is expecting 3 features

Answer (score 1):

You can access the fitted encoder by name (or index): `fitted_encoder = ct.named_transformers_['cat']`

`fitted_encoder.get_feature_names_out()` tells you the output format/features of the encoder, which in this case will be `[x0_blue, x0_green, x0_red]`, indicating the correspondence between colour and the encoding.

To print the actual encodings for a given category, you can cycle through the categories (`fitted_encoder.categories_`) like this:

```py
for category in fitted_encoder.categories_[0]: #iterates over ['blue', 'green', 'red']
    print('input', category, 'encoded as', fitted_encoder.transform([[category]])
```

```py
input blue  encoded as [[1. 0. 0.]]
input green encoded as [[0. 1. 0.]]
input red   encoded as [[0. 0. 1.]]
```

---

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,'red', 14], [4,'blue',54], [2,'green', 241], [7,'blue',25]])
display(
    data
)

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('cat', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False), [1]),],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

tfmd = ct.fit_transform(data)
fitted_encoder = ct.named_transformers_['cat']

display(
    tfmd,
    ct.get_feature_names_out(),
    fitted_encoder.get_feature_names_out(),
    fitted_encoder.categories_
)

for category in fitted_encoder.categories_[0]:
    print('input', category, 'encoded as', fitted_encoder.transform([[category]]))
```